# str_to_date doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Experts, I am going crazy... str_to_date won't work

```
mysql> describe product_tbl;
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ...                | ...         | ...  | ... | ...     | ...            |
| expiration_date    | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Date format is day 01-31 - month 01-12 - year 4 digits

```
mysql> select expiration_date from product_tbl limit 2;
+-----------------+
| expiration_date |
+-----------------+
| 26-09-2017      |
| 19-09-2017      |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

According to documentation at [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

%d -> Day of the month, numeric (00..31)

%m -> Month, numeric (00..12)

%Y -> Year, numeric, four digits

but...

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') from product_tbl limit 2;
+------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                     |
| NULL                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Help appreciated!

---

In response to your questions:

Without LIMIT:

```
mysql> select expiration_date, STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') from product_tbl;
+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| expiration_date | STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| 26-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 20-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| 19-09-2017      | NULL                                     |
| ...             | ...                                      |
```

and so on till the end of the table.

Also,

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    ->   FROM product_tbl
    ->  WHERE expiration_date IS NOT NULL
    ->  LIMIT 2;
+------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                     |
| NULL                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    ->   FROM product_tbl
    ->  ORDER BY expiration_date DESC
    ->  LIMIT 2;
+------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                     |
| NULL                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

By the way, Server version is 5.6.37 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

---

EDIT:

```
mysql> select expiration_date, CAST(expiration_date AS DATE), STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') from product_tbl;
+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| expiration_date | CAST(expiration_date AS DATE) | STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 26-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 23-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 28-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 27-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
| 21-09-2017      | NULL                          | NULL                                     |
```

I suspect my database installation is faulty because on another server running MariaDB 5.5.52 dates are returned correctly.

I've tried to uninstall and re-install MySQL server but same result.
I'm going now to change repository and install a different version.

I will keep you posted.
Thanks anyway for your support.

---

EDIT:

Just to let you know that I removed MySQL Community Server 5.6.37 and installed MariaDB 10.1.26. Now it works like a charm.
Not sure if this is a bug of MySQL but, at least the problem is solved.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. I imagine that in rare cases, it could even account for such behaviour - but I don't know.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://rextester.com/UWT71594

Comment: Change your query to `select expiration_date, STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') from product_tbl limit 2;`  so you can see which dates it's trying to convert.

Comment: can you show the 2 warnings you are getting in your last query?

Comment: Level: Warning
   Code: 1411
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: This seems like weird and exceptional behavior.Query seems fine. Run this query : SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'; after this, re-run your queries and see whether it works!

Comment: try this and let's see the result: `select expiration_date, CAST(expiration_date AS DATE), STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') from product_tbl;`

Answer (score 0):

AS mentioned by Strawberry, you might be getting random records with NULL values

> LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

You may check if you will have records using these queries.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') 
  FROM product_tbl
 WHERE expiration_date IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 2;
```

Or

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(expiration_date, '%d-%m-%Y') 
  FROM product_tbl
 ORDER BY expiration_date DESC
 LIMIT 2;
```